# What input cv2.SimpleBlobDetector() expects?

Tags: python, opencv

My input `mask` is one dimensional grey image:

```
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector()

print('mask.shape', mask.shape) #
print('mask.dtype', mask.dtype) #
mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)
mask = np.dstack([mask] * 3)
print('mask.shape', mask.shape) #
print('mask.dtype', mask.dtype) #
keypoints = detector.detect(mask)

print('type(keypoints)', type(keypoints))
print('keypoints', keypoints)
```

Output:

```
mask.shape (360, 480)
mask.dtype uint8
mask.shape (360, 480, 3)
mask.dtype uint8
```

It produce an error:
`TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its derivative)`

**Update:**

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Circles.jpg',0)

print('img.shape', img.shape)
print('img.dtype', img.dtype)

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()

keypoints = detector.detect(img)

print('type(keypoints)', type(keypoints))
print('keypoints', keypoints)
```

Output:

```
img.shape (428, 500)
img.dtype uint8
type(keypoints) <class 'list'>
keypoints []
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: You say your mask is 1D. But your error says 2D is needed. Please be more specific. In what way is it 1D? Your output looks like the image has gone from grayscale (1 channel) to true color (3 channels). That might be the issue?

Comment: @mrgloom  An alternative approach to this is to use `cv2.findContours()` and filtering techniques to obtain the contours of each blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the backstory, but at some point the way you create a detector object was changed.
This should make your code work:

```
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
```

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html#a1d7a06c8b8749207a978e42cd8d0cdf6)

Comment: For some reason it can't find any blob on black-white gray image.

Comment: Apparently, in a grayscale image the algorithm uses white for background and looks for nonwhite blobs. Because when you invert the image, it detects a bunch of points. To invert the image, put `img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)` right below `img = cv2.imread('Circles.jpg',0)`